# The connection was reset deploying geoserver.war in ubuntu

Tags: geoserver, ubuntu, tomcat, deployment

I have installed Tomcat 7 in Ubuntu and when I try to deploy geoserver.war I receive the error "The connection was reset" in Firefox and "402 Access Denied" in Chromium.

How do I deploy geoserver.war?

Comment: Do you deploy using tomcat manager interface? You could try to upload the file to your tomcat/webapps directory and see if that works. Maybe its about your user not being in the correct manager roles.

Comment: see if there is any message in the tomcat log file or the geoserver log file

Comment: I have in the users file: 
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,manager,manager-gui,manager-script"/>

I don't know where is the tomcat/webapps directory to copy the war file

Comment: Where can I see the tomcat log file?

Comment: It's solved. To deploy it was enough to copy the war file in /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To deploy you can copy the war file in /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted after 48 hours. Learn more [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The real cause of the issue is the max-file-size limit in WEB-INF/web.xml. It is set for 50MB while the geoserver.war (version 2.9.0) is over 65MB.

Open the file below for tomcat7:
sudo nano /usr/share/tomcat7-admin/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml

Locate multipart-config tag and turn 50MB to 500MB.